# Finding prime numbers equal to the sum of squared primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was doing some work on prime numbers, and I came across this problem:

"For prime numbers $p$ and $q$, determine the greatest prime, $r$ less than $100$ for which $r = p^2 + q^2$."
Of course, you can always do it by hand, but I was wondering, are there were any faster methods to solving it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I find the question not very well written. My answer to it would be “Well, it’s obviously p^2+q^2 if it is a prime number” as you fix *p* and *q* beforehand. I would suggest “Find the greatest prime *r < 100* such that $r = p^2+q^2$ for some prime numbers *p* and *q*.

Comment: @Édouard: Yes - or better still "... $r < 100$ that can be expressed as ..." :)

Answer (score 26):

Note that if $p$ and $q$ are odd, then $p^2$ and $q^2$ are also. Then $p^2+q^2$ is even and can't be prime ($2$ can't be written as such a sum). Then necessarily $$r=4+q^2$$
With $r$ less than $100$ the only possible values for $q$ are the primes up to $10$.

Comment: And if you start with the largest such prime first...